# How to set zooming options for pyramid chart of Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I am not able to have zoom in option in pyramid chart of Amcharts . I didn't find any inbuilt attribute as well. Is it possible to have zoom in and zoom out for pyramid charts in Amcharts

Comment: No, there isn't a zoom option for pyramid/funnel charts so it's not possible. If the chart type doesn't have a `chartScrollbar` property in the docs, it's pretty safe to assume that you can't zoom. If the issue is that you have a lot of data and need to focus on a subset of it, consider creating a drilldown, similar to the [pie chart example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/drill-down-pie-chart/)

Comment: Thanks xorspark I already have drill down and yea my main issue is that when I have a large amount of data coming and one data is very marginal compared to others then the slice is too small ... Is there any way to set a min size of the slice ... That's why I wanted to go for an zoom option so that users can zoom and have a look at it

Comment: No as the slice sizes are based on the values. The closest you can do is use fake values as your valueField to influence the size and then have your balloonText reference your actual values. [See this example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c533ad1f863855dd2914995373b71dbf?editors=0010) for more information.